# Stack implementation with singly linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, stack

The following is my implementation of a stack using a linked list.

```
class EmptyStackError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Stack is empty: Invalid Operation!")


class LinkedList:
    class _Node:
        def __init__(self, data, next_node=None):
            self.data = data
            self.next_node = next_node


    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None
        self._tail = None

    def add_first(self, data):
        """ Add data to the beginning of the linked list"""
        node = self._Node(data)
        if not self._head and not self._head:
            self._head = self._tail = node
            return
        node.next_node = self._head
        self._head = node

    def add_last(self, data):
        """ Add data to the end of the linked list """
        node = self._Node(data)
        if not self._head and not self._tail:
            self._head = self._tail = node
            return
        self._tail.next_node = node
        self._tail = node

    def remove_last(self):
        """ Remove the last element in the linked list """
        if not self._head and not self._tail:  # if linked list is empty
            raise EmptyStackError
        elif self._head is self._tail:  # if only one element
            data = self._head.data  # or data of tail
            self._head = self._tail = None
            return data
        data = self._tail.data
        current = self._head
        while current.next_node.next_node:
            current = current.next_node
        current.next_node = None
        self._tail = current
        return data

    def remove_first(self):
        """ Remove the first element in the linked list """
        if not self._head and not self._tail:  # if linked list is empty
            raise EmptyStackError
        elif self._head is self._tail:  # if only one element
            data = self._head.data
            self._head = self._tail = None
            return data
        data = self._head.data
        self._head = self._head.next_node
        return data

    def __str__(self):
        if not self._head and not self._tail:
            return "Stack is empty!!"
        items = []
        current = self._head
        while current:
            items.append(current.data)
            current = current.next_node
        return " ".join([str(i) for i in items])


class Stack:
    """ A stack implementation using a linked list

    Note: The reason add_first and remove_first are using for push and pop respectively is to keep them O(1).
          If adding and removing last were used, then remove last would O(n).
          This is because deleting the tail would require the traversal of the linked list to delete the last element.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = LinkedList()

    def push(self, data):
        self.items.add_first(data)

    def pop(self):
        data = self.items.remove_first()
        return data

    def peek(self):
        data = self.items.remove_first()
        self.items.add_first(data)
        return data

    def __str__(self):
        string = self.items.__str__()
        return string
```

Is there anything I need to improve? whether it's style or logic.

Can you find any bugs? Whether in the linked list or the stack.

My basic tests:

```
import pytest

def test_push():
    """ This is depending on another method """
    stack = Stack()
    stack.push(5)
    assert stack.peek() == 5

def test_pop():
    stack = Stack()
    stack.push(5)
    data = stack.pop()
    assert data == 5

def test_empty_pop():
    stack = Stack()
    with pytest.raises(EmptyStackError):
        stack.pop()

def test_peek():
    stack = Stack()
    stack.push(5)
    assert stack.peek() == 5

def test_empty_peek():
    stack = Stack()
    with pytest.raises(EmptyStackError):
        stack.peek()

test_push()
test_pop()
test_empty_pop()
test_peek()
test_empty_peek()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have a typo/mistake in `if not self._head and not self._head`, I think you wanted to write `self._tail` in one of them.
2. I do not see the interest of making `Node()` inner to `LinkedList()`. In opposite, doing so condemns you not to reuse the `Node()` code and slaughters your code [scalability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) (in case you will need to add functionality to your code by implementing a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)), for example)
3. You can refactor this code into one function and call it when necessary:

   ```
   if not self._head and not self._head:
       self._head = self._tail = node
       return
   ```
4. While it apparently does the job, the `return` statement of your code in (3) is not in the right place. You should remove it and use the `if ... else` statements instead because this makes sense and that is what the reader of your code may expect.
5. Here, we can use more common sense: `if not self._head and not self._tail`: honestly, if the head is `None`, it must be obvious the tail is in the same condition. I mean you can replace similar lines to simply: `if not self._head`
6. You said you want to code a **stack**: by definition, in a stack, we need only a pointer to its head. The head is the tail, and the tail is the head because that is where operations occur.
7. Do not code what you do not need: it is unnecessary to use `add_last()` and `remove_last()`. Why? Because you are coding a **stack**, and a stack follows the principle of [**LIFO**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_and_LIFO_accounting#LIFO), so do not care  about the other end at all. In a stack, we need to perform the push and pop operations; at best, we would like to know its size, everything else does not belong to the stack notion.
8. The points (6) and (7) are a gentle introduction to what I will tell you here: you misunderstood the stack implementation: we can implement a stack using an array or a simple linked list. You chose the later one but you misunderstood it because you lost yourself in  implementing a linked list and you ended up by missing the notion of the stack.

**If you carefully read [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Linked_list), for example, you will understand that stack implementation using linked lists does not require you to implement a linked list and its different operations but simply having a data structure which looks like a node that belongs to a linked list, and by designing the pop and push operations, your stack will look, by default, as a singly linked a list.** So based on your code, let me share with you the right way to implement a stack based on linked lists:

```
class EmptyStack(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Stack is empty: invalid operation!')

class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.next = None

class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size

    def push(self, item):
        self.node = Node()
        self.node.data = item
        self.node.next = self.head
        self.head = self.node
        self.size += 1

    def pop(self):
        if self.head == None:
            raise EmptyStack
        self.head_item = self.head.data
        self.head = self.head.next
        self.size -= 1
        return self.head_item



if __name__ == '__main__':
    stack = Stack()
    for i in range(10):
        stack.push(i)
    print('size: {}'.format(stack.get_size()))
    print(stack.pop())
    print(stack.get_size())
```

Comment: 'simply linked list': did you mean 'singly'?

Comment: Both notions are used in the litterature and they are both correct, but there is a typo I guess, '**simple**' not 'simply', so thank you@Coal_

Comment: Great great answer. Points 1, 2, 3 were right on the money. Point 4 is because I love early exit from functions, but you are right. The code is readable when replacing the return with if else. I did not do it for remove_last though. A while loop inside an else statement makes me uncomfortable :). For point 5, I knew that when I wrote it. I just overdid it with both checks just as a form of catching myself making mistakes in moving the tail and head nodes during other operations

Comment: You are also quite correct in points 6, 7 and 8. I kinda did them on purpose since I wanted to write a linked list anyways. But I should have removed them from the code I've posted here.

Comment: Now everything after 8 surprised me. I always thought implementing a stack with linked list meant creating a linked list class. I noticed when I was done with the Stack class that I did not do anything stack-related. All of my code was for the linked list. I found it odd, but carried on. Now that I see your implementation, I get it. The simplicity of it and the fact that it's actually the stack logic I wanted to practice makes me appreciate your answer even more. Thank you Begueradj. I truly appreciate your time.